# DB2 Iterating throught the rows for creating XML file

Tags: php, xml, db2

I am following this tutorial for adding markers to certain addresses from my DB2 database onto the google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3
I am at the part where I try to create an XML document from my DB2 database and am getting a little confused. This is the code that google wrote for iterating through the rows and creating an XML document out of it:

```
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}
```

What would be an equivalent way of doing so in DB2 using PHP?

Comment: I guess it would be exactly the same, except you'd replace `mysql_fetch_assoc()` with `db2_fetch_assoc()`, no?

Comment: I tried that and I get the error that 'name' is not a valid index. Same for all the other attributes.

Comment: You may need to use _valid_ column names. Hint: In DB2 (and in the SQL standard) object names are converted to uppercase by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a corresponding PHP DB2 API which may involve enabling the extension in the php ini file and possibly installing a DB2 ODBC driver:

- [DB2_Connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php)
- [PHP Manual - PDO_IBM](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.connection.php)
- [IBM Manual - PDO_IBM](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.php.doc/doc/t0023135.html)

Below is a working example using PDO Driver method with try/catch on the connection. Alternatively, you can use a DSN (see manuals above):

```
# Opening db connection
try {
    $conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);   

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
    $result = db2_execute($stmt);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

while($row = db2_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {  
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}

# Closing db connection
db2_close($conn);
```

Comment: Hey @parfait, I was wondering if it is doable without PDO drivers. I mean I can successfully connect my database. I am using db2_connect method to connect and db2_prepare and db2_execute.

Comment: Then what is the issue? Simple fetch from your executed query, replacing the `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Use [`db2_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-fetch-assoc.php). See edit.

Comment: That is exactly what I did before. Followed exactly but replaced $row = mysql.... with db2_fetch_assoc. I kept getting error that 'name' is not a valid index. 'address' is not a valid index. 'lat' is not a valid index and so on for all the column names

Comment: Hmm I do not know what I did differently but now it seems to work. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Why didn't you mention the errors in your post? I see you did in the comments. Might be your connection, prepare/execution objects? If helped, please select my answer.